# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1) . 4^n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1) . 4^n} $ 
Can anyone tell me how to approach? It must be convergent as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}$ is convergent. and answer will be less than 4/3.
but how to approach I can not see?

Comment: Can you show that $\frac{1}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{4^n}\leq\frac{1}{4^n}$ and use the comparison test?

Comment: Note that this is the same as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)} (\frac 1 4)^n$, which is a power series where $x = \frac 1 4$

Comment: Sorry but the tags (ramanujan-summation) and (summation-by-parts) are offtopic here. The tag (summation) is offtopic as well, but the reason is more subtle. Anyway, please check the meaning of the tags before using them.

Comment: See also: [Sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n(2n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693720). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B(2n%2B1)%20.%204%5En%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{(2n+1)4^n}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(1/2)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Now for $1\ge x>-1,$ $$\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}3-\cdots$$

$$\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=?$$

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365516/why-does-the-taylor-series-of-ln-1-x-only-approximate-it-for-1x-le-1

Comment: correct the rang of x @lab

Comment: @sani, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)4^n}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{1/2}t^{2n}dt=2\int_0^{1/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^{2n}dt=\int_0^{1/2}\frac2{1-t^2}\:dt
$$ the latter may be evaluated by a partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n = \frac{1}{1-q}$$ 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
$$\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} = \int\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \tanh^{-1}(x)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1} = \frac{\tanh^{-1}(x)}{x}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^{n}}{2n+1} = \frac{\\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{t}}$$
Now evaluate at $t=1/4$

Comment: Note that $\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}=0.5(\log(x+1)-\log(1-x))=arctanh(x)$