# Calculating the following series: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(−1)^k2k+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here are the series:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(−1)^k}{2k+1} $$

I don't know how to start because obviously can't compute all the values up to infinity. My only thought is to use  d'alembert ratio? but doesn't this only tell me if the series converges? not what the actual sum of the series is?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: i can not read this

Comment: Do you mean $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^k2k+1\:?$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227555/compute-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac12n1-4n

Comment: Why are they both the same series? I fixed it so it looks nicer but I'm still confused.

Comment: hey! sorry not sure ho to write mathematically on here. yes Italy 4 that is right except should be (-1)^k / 2k +1

Comment: I suspect one of them is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k/(2k+1)$.

Comment: Yes, Lord Shark the Unknown that is exactly right

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

By summation of the geometric series,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^{2k}=\frac1{1+x^2}$$ and integrating term-wise over $[0,x)$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\arctan x.$$